# C# MongoDB joins and lookup

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, lookup

I'm new to MongoDB trying to wrap my head around `lookup` `aggregate` and `joins` using these simple classes

```
public class Car
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    // List of supported engine IDs
    public List<string> EngineIds { get; set; }

    public List<string> TireIds { get; set; }

    // This is probably not the best way to do this but it's here while testing
    [BsonIgnore]
    public List<Engine> Engines { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    public List<Tire> Tires { get; set; }
}

public class Engine
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public double Volume { get; set; }
}

public class Tire
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

Running the following Linq query is my issue, while it does find and return the correct Car item from the DB it does not include the related Engines or Tires (I tried both).

```
//This returns the correct car but without filling the Engines prop
//How to also get related tires ? multiple queries ?
var car123 = DataService.CarCollection.Aggregate()
    .Match(c => c.Id == "123")
    .Lookup<Car, Engine, Car>(
        DataService.EngineCollection,
        c => c.EngineIds,
        e => e.Id,
        car => car.Engines
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Another issue is how to include both Engines and Tires relating to my main object Car using a single query?

Comment: This won't work because `TireIds` is a list of `string` whereas `EngineCollection.Id` is an ObjectId so MongoDB has a type mismatch (even if the values look the same). You have to convert your data first so that both Lookup properties have the same types and the same values

Comment: Tried that doesn't seem to change anything. According to other answers `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` allows you to write queries using string even if mongodb internally uses ObjectId.

Comment: But if MongoDB stores internally `ObjectId` as `Id` and you're trying to run `$lookup` against a list of strings then it will not work - types have to be the same in the database